# Assign an outside JavaScript variable inside a ASP.NET user control that is loaded using Ajax

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax

I have a user control that assigns a JavaScript variable that is defined inside another script file. This user control is compiled by a ASP.NET generic handler into HTML and then its markup is pasted by JQuery Ajax inside specified container. The problem is that the assignment script is not being pasted with compiled user control HTML. This is my JavaScript code that resides inside a JavaScript file:

```
var xyz;
function initEnvironment(){
$.ajax({
        url: handlerURL,
        type: "POST",
        data: JSON.stringify(
            {
                XSRFToken: xsrf_token,
                Data: ajaxData
            })
        ,
        dataType: "json",
        cache: true,
        async: IsAjaxAsync,
        beforeSend: null,
        success: function (data) {
                $('#containerDiv').html(data); //this must contain assignment statement for xyz
                alert(xyz); //xyz is null here
        }
    });
}
```

And this is user control C# code that should assign the variable:

```
Literal1.Text = litHtml + @"<script type='text/javascript'>
            xyz = " + xyz + ";</script>";
```

`litHtml` contains some HTML code which is successfully pasted inside the container but the concatenated script code is not pasting. What can be the reason?

**UPDATE**

`xyz` at JavaScript side is a JSON object.

Comment: What does `xyz` look like? If it's a string you need to escape it: `xyz = '" + xyz + "'`

Answer (score 0):

Instead of setting xyz using a literal for the script tag, try using RegisterStartup script to execute a funciton that will set it.  You might have to decode and encode the json object.

Server Side

```
ClientScriptManager cs = Page.ClientScript;
cs.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "SetXYZ", "SetXYZ(" + xyz + ")");
```

Client Side

```
function SetXYZ(xyzVal)
{
  xyz = xyzVal;
}
```

You might also be able to simply do this as well

```
cs.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "SetXYZ", @"<script type='text/javascript'>
        xyz = " + xyz + ";</script>");
```

Comment: And it's just printing the script on the page instead of executing.

Comment: Did you try calling a function instead of trying to output a script block?  Call it using a already setup function passing the xyz.  You might have to pass xyz as a string in single quotes and then parse it in javascript function.  This should work just fine.